# How to write a string of comma separated integers in google sheet as a string?

Tags: python, integer, string-formatting, google-sheets-api, gspread

update: I have a sequence of comma-separated integers as a column in a data frame. 
So, for example one entry is '1234,5678' (this is a list of IDs).
When I try to write this in a csv, Excel recognizes this as a huge integer, the commas are removed and the format is number. So at the end I see 12.345.678. 
The same happens when writing to a google sheet (what I actually need).

Here is a working example using the google api

```py
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from gspread_dataframe import set_with_dataframe
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from gspread_formatting import *

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df.loc[1] = ['name1,names2', '1234,5678', 0.45]
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(str)

email_adress = 'myname@gmail.de'
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
secret_file = 'google_client_secret.json'
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(secret_file, scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
geo_wb = client.create('Test format string1')
geo_wb.share(email_adress, perm_type='user', role='writer')
ws_groups = geo_wb.add_worksheet(title="Region Groups", rows="50", cols="50")

fmt = cellFormat(
    backgroundColor=color(1, 0.9, 0.9),
    textFormat=textFormat(bold=True, foregroundColor=color(1, 0, 1)),
    horizontalAlignment='CENTER'
    )

format_cell_range(ws_groups, 'A2:C2', fmt)
set_with_dataframe(worksheet=ws_groups, dataframe=df)
```

Here is the code for .csv

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
df.loc[1] = ['name1,names2', '1234,5678', 0.45]
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype(str)
df.to_csv('test1.csv')
```

I expect the output to be just 1234,5678. 
Using a different delimiter so 1234; 5678 would solve the problem, but it is really requested to be a comma.

Does anyone know how to simply pre-define the format of one column using the google sheet api in Python to be a string?

I searched in the documentation but only much more complicated examples are described and I couldn't figure it for my case. At the moment I use the gspread and gspread_dataframe packages.

p.s. I think I almost figured it out, but I am not sure, there is a package gspread_formatting, and a cellFormat function to specify the format of a cell. But I can't find how to specify just a cell to be a string (plain text). It seems this is more just for the color, text format (bold etc), as written in the code. Maybe someone knows what exactly do I need to add?

Comment: Hi. See if `df.to_csv('test1.csv', sep=';')` solves it.

Comment: It is excel that is formatting it differently. Open the .csv file in notepad & it is in the format as you have in the dataframe.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Aryerez, that also doesn't help :(. I have German Excel so I tried ',' and gives me the same result (if I write ; it doesn't separate at all). But as I mentioned at the end, I actually write to a google sheet, so I need a more general solution I think.

Comment: thanks, @SH-SF ! I understand. so I guess now I have to focus on searching how to pre-format the columns in a google sheet with the api.

Comment: may be you can close this question.

Comment: @SH-SF I would like to, but my initial problem is not solved (as posed in the title). I hope to get an answer to it, because I couldn't figure it out myself from the documentation or other sources.

Comment: Show your google sheets API code you have so far.

Comment: @ilmiacs good point, I edited the post with that code now. any hints?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution (and actually the single one so far) is to use not only comma but a space as a delimiter. If the string is "1234, 4567" then it won't be recognized as a number any more.